# How do I scrape ::before element in a website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to scrape phone number from this website using selenium. I found the class to be "tel ttel" but when I try to scrape the website by find_element_by_xpath. I get an empty string.

My code:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Spardha-Mithra-IAS-KAS-Coaching-Centre-Opposite-Maruthi-Medicals-Vijayanagar/080PXX80-XX80-140120184741-R6P8_BZDET?xid=QmFuZ2Fsb3JlIEJhbmsgRXhhbSBUdXRvcmlhbHM='
wd.get(url)
phone = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="tel ttel"]').text
print(phone)
```

Output:

> ' '

The phone number is located over here:
[image: Phone-number]

The Inspect element for the phone number is:
[image: Inspect Element]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: They have apparently not put the phone number as text so that it's harder to scrape. Instead they have put icons for each number.

Comment: @JeffC I am sorry. I will keep this in mind while asking questions in future

Comment: The point is for you to fix it now and in the future. Please edit this question and replace the pictures with text.

Comment: @JeffC - a screenshot of the inspector panel (that's not code) is actually more helpful in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need selenium. The instructions to apply the content which gives the pseudo [before](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) elements their values is carried in the css style instructions:

[image]

Here, the 2/3 letter strings after the `.icon-` e.g. `acb` map to the `span` elements which house your `before` content. The values after `\9d0` are + 1 of the actual value shown. You can create a dictionary from these pairs of values (with the adjustment) to decode the number at each `before` from the `span` class value.

Example of how 2/3 letter strings map to content:

[image]

My method is perhaps a little verbose as I am not that familiar with Python but the logic should be clear.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Spardha-Mithra-IAS-KAS-Coaching-Centre-Opposite-Maruthi-Medicals-Vijayanagar/080PXX80-XX80-140120184741-R6P8_BZDET?xid=QmFuZ2Fsb3JlIEJhbmsgRXhhbSBUdXRvcmlhbHM='
res  = requests.get(url, headers  = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

cipherKey = str(soup.select('style[type="text/css"]')[1])
keys = re.findall('-(\w+):before', cipherKey, flags=0)
values = [int(item)-1 for item in re.findall('9d0(\d+)', cipherKey, flags=0)]
cipherDict = dict(zip(keys,values))
cipherDict[list(cipherDict.keys())[list(cipherDict.values()).index(10)]] = '+'
decodeElements = [item['class'][1].replace('icon-','') for item in soup.select('.telCntct span[class*="icon"]')]

telephoneNumber = ''.join([str(cipherDict.get(i)) for i in decodeElements])
print(telephoneNumber)
```

Comment: Thank you so much you guyz are awesome!!

Comment: but can you tell me why is the code not working for this website "'https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/TIME-Yelahanka-Above-Bank-of-Baroda-Yelahanka-New-Town/080PXX80-XX80-150128200021-F9K8_BZDET?xid=QmFuZ2Fsb3JlIENhdCBUdXRvcmlhbHM='" structure of the page and everything is same. even though its not working

Comment: Thank you so much @QHarr. I wish I could upvote it more than once. Can you tell me why was'nt it working before and what things have you changed.

Comment: The css selector needed to be changed to be one that would work across different pages so I changed that. I also decided to add in the handling of "+". The keys that appear seem to always be the same but are randomly ordered each time page is loaded. Index 10 of dictionary will always be the "+" and the other items map as discussed. I also edited out my use of string splitting and left it with regex. Looks a little more readable. You can always view the prior version in the edit history.

Comment: This is unable to differentiate multiple numbers (the comma separator is in html later). Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Please give an example url and the expected number to return - you may need to open a new question

Comment: Thank you for quick reply :) [This](https://www.justdial.com/Coimbatore/3-C-S-Sree-Foundation-Play-School-Bharathi-Park-Saibaba-Colony/0422PX422-X422-130206210026-I4K4_BZDET?xid=Q29pbWJhdG9yZSBQbGF5Z3JvdXBzIFNhaWJhYmEgQ29sb255)  is one. I could also open new question if needed for this. Please let me know.

Comment: I'll have a look this evening as looks kinda fun!

Comment: kindly help. It is also not working currently for single number also. For [this](https://www.justdial.com/Coimbatore/Point-Sales-Service-Coimbatore-Central/0422PX422-X422-120618174616-H9U9_BZDET?xid=Q29pbWJhdG9yZSBQdW1wIERlYWxlcnM=) link, I am getting 9132846529 instead of 9152357193

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the `:before` content from the computed style:

```
chars = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.telCntct a.tel span')].map(span => window.getComputedStyle(span,':before').content)")
```

But in this case you're left with weird unicode content that you then have to map to numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much you guyz are awesome!!

Comment: can you please help me with the same thing using beautiful soup. It would be very kind of you.

Comment: Without a browser you will need to follow QHarr's answer

Comment: Awesome answer. +